# Comparing gold standard csv file and extracted values csv files in Python

Tags: python, regex, csv

This is for a data mining task where we are automating scoring of the quality of the extraction. 
There is a gold standard csv that might consist of the the fields that look like

golden_standard.csv

```
| id | description             | amount  | date       |
|----|-------------------------|---------|------------|
| 1  | Some description.       | $150.54 | 12/12/2012 |
| 2  | Some other description. | $200    | 10/10/2015 |
| 3  | Other description.      | $25     | 11/11/2014 |
| 4  | My description          | $11.35  | 01/01/2015 |
| 5  | Your description.       | $20     | 03/03/2013 |
```

, and then there are two possible extraction results files:

extract1.csv

```
| id | description             | date       |
|----|-------------------------|------------|
| 1  | Some description.       | 12/12/2012 |
| 2  | Some other description. | 10/10/2015 |
| 3  | Other description.      | 11/11/2014 |
| 4  | 122333222233332221      | 11/11/2014 |
| 5  | Your description.       | 03/03/2013 |
```

extract2.csv

```
| id | description             | amount  | date       |
|----|-------------------------|---------|------------|
| 1  | Some description.       | $150.54 | 12/12/2012 |
| 2  | Some other description. | $200    | 10/10/2015 |
| -  | ----------------------- | -----   | ---------- |
| 5  | Your description.       | $20     | 03/03/2013 |
```

extract3.csv

```
| Garbage  | More Garbage       |
| Garbage  | More Garbage       |
```

And I would like to have my program report that extract 1 is missing a column and that values are not properly matched in column 2.

For the second case, I am missing entries and that some rows are all mismatched.

In the last case, resulting csv was all screwed up, but I still want program to detect some meaningful abberation.

Does anyone have some quick and clever way in python to do this kind of comparison?

I have my regular, longish row-by-row and column-by-column iterative way that I could post here, but I am thinking that there might be a quicker, more elegant Pythonic way to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by _csv_, what are the actual delimiters?

Comment: Commas, but I could use tabs or whatever if that simplifies the case. I control the format.

Comment: The first level check is to split on the delimiter. Do this for each line. In the line loop, just validate the field info for each array position. This is the simplest way to do it. You can always break out of the loop, say if you're missing a column.

Comment: Will you always have the `id` column for at least the standard and the first and second extracts?

Comment: No, this is just for illustration.

Comment: I have a partial solution but I'm not sure it works until you've tested it. Wait a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer: My approach uses the `pandas` library.**

First, data set-up.

**gold_std.csv**

```
id,description,amount,date
1,Some description.,$150.54,12/12/2012
2,Some other description.,$200,10/10/2015
3,Other description.,$25,11/11/2014
4,My description,$11.35,01/01/2015
5,Your description.,$20,03/03/2013
```

**extract1.csv**

```
id,description,date
1,Some description.,12/12/2012
2,Some other description.,10/10/2015
3,Other description.,11/11/2014
4,122333222233332221,11/11/2014
5,Your description.,03/03/2013
```

**extract2.csv**

```
id,description,amount,date
1,Some description.,$150.54,12/12/2012
2,Some other description.,$200,10/10/2015
3,Other description.,$25,11/11/2014
5,Your description.,$20,03/03/2013
```

Second, code.

```
import pandas as pd

def compare_extract(extract_name, reference='gold_std.csv'):

    gold = pd.read_csv(reference)
    ext = pd.read_csv(extract_name)

    gc = set(gold.columns)
    header = ext.columns
    extc = set(header)

    if gc != extc:
        missing = ", ".join(list(gc - extc))
        print "Extract has the following missing columns: {}".format(missing)
    else:
        print "Extract has the same column as standard. Checking for abberant rows..."
        gold_list = gold.values.tolist()
        ext_list = ext.values.tolist()
        # Somewhat non-pandaic approach because possible no same IDs so we're relying
        # on set operations instead. A bit hackish, actually.
        diff = list(set(map(tuple, gold_list)) - set(map(tuple, ext_list)))
        df = pd.DataFrame(diff, columns=header)
        print "The following rows are not in the extract: "
        print df
```

Third, test runs.

```
e1 = 'extract1.csv'
compare_extract(e1)
# Extract has the following missing columns: amount

e2 = 'extract2.csv'
compare_extract(e2)
# Extract has the same column as standard. Checking for abberant rows...
# The following rows are not in the extract: 
#    id     description  amount        date
# 0   4  My description  $11.35  01/01/2015
```

Finally, the last extract is a bit arbitrary. I think for that one you're better off writing a non-`pandas` algorithm.